# how do you empty out the divs that belong to the inactive tabs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have web page that has tabs on top. Depending on the tab that I click, I load data based on the tab. This is my script. Each tab has lots of data to show. When I click on tab, it shows me data about set of application and another tab shows about different app and so forth. I have about 30 tabs. What I would like to do is, when I click on a tab, I want that tab to be active and my whole page should have data about that tab and that tab only. If the tab is not clicked, the data about unclicked tab should not be on the page. The divs that contain the data about the unclicked tabs should be empty. This is my script. Any ideas how would empty out the divs that belong to the unclicked tabs?

```
<script>
            // Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
                    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
                    // which tab is active and it's associated content
                    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

                    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
                    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
                    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                    $active.addClass('active');
                    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

                    // Hide the remaining content
                    $links.not($active).each(function () {
                        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();

                    });

                    // Bind the click event handler
                    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
                        // Make the old tab inactive.
                        $active.removeClass('active');
                        $content.hide();

                        // Update the variables with the new link and content
                        $active = $(this);
                        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                        // Make the tab active.
                        $active.addClass('active');
                        $content.show();

                        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see code below :

```
// Make the old tab inactive.
$active.removeClass('active');
$content.html('');  //  <----- add this line
$content.hide();
```

Comment: let's say I clicked on tab2, then tab3. If I go back and click tab2 again, I dont see any content if follow your answer.

Comment: You said "What I would like to do is, when I click on a tab, I want that tab to be active and my whole page should have data about that tab and that tab only." this suggested me you wanted the info deleted. After this you should use .load() to re-load the info on each click. If this is not the case, I don't understand what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: where to you put the $content.load()?

Comment: On the click event function of the tab.